# What's wrong with my syntax or my mysql?

Tags: mysql

```
mysql> use web;
Database changed
mysql> DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `download`;
Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE `download` (   `file_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',   `location` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
ERROR 1050 (42S01): Table '`web`.`download`' already exists
mysql> INSERT INTO `download` (`file_id`, `location`) VALUES (3, 'a.pdf');
ERROR 1146 (42S02): Table 'web.download' doesn't exist
```

or what am I doing wrong? Logs show nothing - no errors.

Comment: Looks like an error in system database. Common source of such problem - the table body files were deleted externally. Recommendation - recreate the database. The fastest way seems to be: remove FKs and triggers, copy tables to temp database (create table copy in another DB, detach tablespace, copy table body, import tablespace; for small tables use common CREATE TABLE LIKE + INSERT SELECT), copy functions/procedures, drop abd recreate DB, move the tables back, recreate FKs and triggers.

Comment: When I was posting my answer I did not see this comment, but please post this as the answer and I will accept it. I solved this by dropping and recreating after all so this is right on the money. Edit: ping added. @Akina

Comment: Immediately after `Query OK, 0 rows affected, 1 warning (0.00 sec)` do `SHOW WARNINGS;`

Comment: @RickJames - that's a hella nice lead. If this ever repeats, I will, my thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by dropping the schema and recreating it from backup.